# How to design for optional extras which are conditionally available?

Tags: forms, usability

We have an online app for flower deliveries. For any given order the customer can specify a delivery date, and two more options.

If the floral arrangement is to be delivered today (and the order is being placed before 4pm) then they can also request it be rush delivered. Obviously we don't offer rush delivery for future-dated deliveries, because we've got plenty of time to ensure they get out the door first thing in the morning. There is also an extra charge for rush deliveries.

The other option we offer is to set up a repeating schedule, like sending a fresh arrangement to your office every week. Again, we don't offer rush delivery for repeating deliveries.

To keep things simple (and because our the courier system we integrate with is a little bit funky) we don't let the customer request a rush delivery for today with repeats to follow.

Designing the form options for this is challenging us. We've considered radio buttons and also checkboxes and even tabbed panels, with solutions having parts that disable interactively depending on the date field and possibly the two options.

At this time we don't have any other delivery options other than those three: date, rush, and repeat. Rush isn't a big seller but it is a big delighter so we don't want to hide it away. Conversely `repeat` is a popular option, although more a must-have-available option than a delighter.

This part of the order form is at the pointy end of the order process and thus doesn't need a glamorous treatment (the customer is already convinced they want to order) and so usability is a driver.

I'm stumped and am looking for fresh ideas, so I'll refrain from showing what we've done so far.

How would you design this?

Comment: Can you add wireframes?

Comment: @dnbrv The OP stated - "I'm stumped and am looking for fresh ideas, so I'll refrain from showing what we've done so far."

Comment: Note to self: Don't post to SE before waking up completely. =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can split one behind-the scenes option in multiple options for the users. For instance, you may offer

1. Rush delivery
2. Later today
3. Tomorrow
4. Later date...
5. Weekly...
6. Monthly...
7. Other frequency...

Comment: +1 because the core question is "when do you want this delivered?", which is simply a list of options. If you can list out these "when delivered" options, it should cover everything.